# Want to fire Intent after getting success==true from web service else incorrect/username password in asynctask?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm  using web service through asynctask for login purpose.I am passing values username and password and in return getting back json of {"success":"true"} or {"success":"false"} .If true then it should fire intent and go to next activity else it should display incorrect username/password but i don't know why intent is not working in onPostExecute. Please help me.

**This is my code**

```
public class Dashboard extends Activity {

    TextView map;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public String jArray;
    public Boolean login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        Button rtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonsubmit);
        EditText edit_text1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText edit_text2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String username=edit_text1.getEditableText().toString();
        Log.d("username",username);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        EditText edit_text1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText edit_text2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String username=edit_text1.getEditableText().toString();
        String password=edit_text2.getEditableText().toString();

        if(username==null)
        {
            map.setText("Please enter something");
        }
        else if(username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "empty value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
        Log.d("user",username);
        Log.d("password",password);
        new MyAsyncTaskMapNoGet().execute();

        }
    }

    public boolean webservreqMAPNOGET(){
        try {
            //HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            //HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            //HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);            
            HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
            p.setParameter("user", "1");
            // Instantiate an HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(p);
            EditText edit_text1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText edit_text2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            String username=edit_text1.getEditableText().toString();
            String password=edit_text2.getEditableText().toString();
            Log.d("username1",username);
            String url = url;
            Log.d("url",url );

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Instantiate a GET HTTP method
            try {
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - start");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "1"));
                httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                Log.d("respnse",responseBody);

                // Parse
                JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                String jArray = json1.getString("success");
                Log.d("success", jArray);
                if(jArray=="true")
                {
                Boolean login=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Boolean login=false;
                }
                return true;
            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        } 
        catch (Throwable t) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }        
    }

     public class MyAsyncTaskMapNoGet extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
        {        
            ProgressDialog mProgressDialog3;
            private String json1;
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                mProgressDialog3.dismiss();
                mProgressDialog3.dismiss();
                mProgressDialog3.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPreExecute() {
                mProgressDialog3 = ProgressDialog.show(Dashboard.this, "Loading...", "Data is Loading...");
            }

            @Override
            public Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if(webservreqMAPNOGET()){
                    Log.d("yay","SUCCESS");

                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("err","ERROR");
                    return false;
                }
            }
                public void onPostExecute() { 
                    // dismiss the dialog once done 

                    if(login)
{       
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.esstel___ippbx.secondactivity"));
}                       
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "incorrect username/password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                } 

        }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onPostExecute` to

```
   @Override
   public void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   mProgressDialog3.dismiss(); 
   if(result) // true
    { 
            // start activity    
    }
   else
   {
            // display toast 
   }
   }
```

Why do you have 3 statments  `mProgressDialog3.dismiss()` remove the other two.

Also remove this you already have a Overriden `onPostExecute`

```
   public void onPostExecute() {
```

Also you are get the text from editext in doInbackground. Initialize edittext's  as a class member. Initialize in `onCreate`. get the text on button click. pass the values directly to doInbackground or to the constructor asynctask and use the same.

Also

```
  public class Dashboard extends Activity implements OnClickListenr{
```

In onCreate

```
  rtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Also there is no need to initialize views every time. Initialize it in `onCreate` once

Comment: Thank you for you answer ! Can you please tell me how to pass jArray value which is returned back as json string to pass to onPreExecute method for checking so that if true intent will fire else toast will display

Comment: @user2671225 check the asynctask docs. read it carefully. you will know http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @user2671225 the result of doinbackground computation is param to `onPostExecute` you return true or false in `doInabckground`. So just use the above `onPostExecute` and it should work and remove the duplicate

Comment: @user2671225 asked 3 questions accepted none. if it helps you should aceept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are having two postExecute method in your asynctask. The logic for transmitting to a new activity is mentioned in your custom postexecute method (not the overridden one ). As you are having two postexecutes, your async task is only identifying the first overridden one . you need to call your custom postexecute method from the overidden method like::

```
 @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            mProgressDialog3.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog3.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog3.dismiss();
            onPostExecute();
        }
```

Also your TextView map is not initialised.you are doing a setText() to an uninitialised textView ,as a result it will give a NPE.